# Need help getting this Spring 3/AJAX/JSON drop down population working

Tags: java, ajax, json, spring

I am trying to do a Spring MVC 3 ajax call to populate a drop down from json serialized data.

The problem I am seeing is I am not sure what format of JSON Spring is returning for my list, and why.

The method which returns the Ajax data looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getMyObjects", method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public List<MyObject> getMyObjects () {

 List<MyObject> myobjects = // populate list

 return myobjects;
```

}

And as far as I understand that should be all I need to do, right?

In my app logs I see it is indeed converting the response to JSON, as follows:

2012-06-20 11:08:21,125 DEBUG (AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:139) - Written [[MyObject [id=1376, name=Something test], MyObject [id=1234 name=More test]]] as "application/json;charset=UTF-8" using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter@d1b7e5]

But that JSON string looks odd to me, is that valid?

I was expecting stuff like [{ id : 1376, name="Something test"}, { id : 1234, name="More test"}]

On the client side when I get the response and do an alert I see it says its an array of objects like this: [Object object] [Object object] and I dont know how to deal with this data.

I try:
alert(data); -- gives the output I just described above
                    $(data).each(function() {
                      alert(this.id); // undefined!
                    });

How do I use this kind of JSON data or how do I convert it to something more manageable?

[Edit] Attaching my client side code with current alert responses I am trying:
    $.ajax({
      type : "POST",
      url : "getMyObjects",
      success : function(data) {
        alert(data); // [Object object] [Object object]
        alert(data.value); // Undefined
        $(data).each(function() {
          alert(this.id); // Undefined for each iteration
        });
      },
      error : function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(textStatus);
      }
    });

Comment: I think that is correct, your response will be object. try something like alert(data.value);

Comment: Could you post a sample JSON output from your call to getMyObjects?

Comment: Andre, yes its in the post but a bit buried in there ;) here it is isolated: [[MyObject [id=1376, name=Something test], MyObject [id=1234 name=More test]]]

Comment: thinksteep, alert(data.value) ... Undefined.

Comment: Here is my client side code with alert responses: `$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : "getMyObjects",
    success : function(data) {
     alert(data); // [Object object] [Object object]
     alert(data.value); // Undefined
     $(data).each(function() {
       alert(this.id); // Undefined for each iteration
     });
    },
    error : function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
     alert(textStatus);
    }
   });`

Comment: Have you tried `var obj = JSON.parse(data)` so far ? Or specifying JSON type in jQuery ajax function for automated parsing `dataType : 'json'`

Comment: 'dataType : 'json'` to the ajax paramters had no effect. `var obj = JSON.parse(data);` produces browser error, but `var obj = $.parseJSON(data);` passes but the result: `alert(obj);` // prints null`

Comment: Install Firefox + Firebug or Chrome and see what your method actually returns. I return lists (but wrapped within a container class to provide auxiliary information on the list - for dojo controls) and the lists return just fine as `[{blah:blah},{blah:blah}]`etc.

Comment: Ok, I used Firebug and it turns out the format sent to the browser is different, it looks more like a JSON string as I would expect: [{"id":"2494","name":"Something test"},{"id":"1234","name":"More test"}]

Answer (score 0):

Spring 3 provides integration with [DWR](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/documentation/server/integration/spring.html)(direct web remoting) which is very cool framwrork for AJAX calls. In DWR you can handle lists very easily just like in core java.

Answer (score 0):

This is it! you should get the json format that you were expected. no more code (parser, formatting ) in necessary.

What you dont see is the actual json returned. well you try your url right away in the browser without calling it by ajax like `http://yourdomain/yourservlet/getMyObjects` you then will see your json as it is.

or else, use firfox with firebug, and you can see your ajac call (request & and response)

**UPDATE**

```
$.ajax({
url: "path/to/your/url",
cache: false,
async: false,
success: function(data){                    
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        alert(data[i].id);
        alert(data[i].name);
    }
}
```

});

Comment: I was able to hit the URL directly, and it got the following response: [{"id":"2494","name":"Something test"},{"id":"1234","name":"More test"}].

Comment: But still I cant seem to access this data using javascript/jquery. I am now trying .getJSON jquery, with the follwing code inside the call: `alert("result = "+textStatus+", data = "+data);
     $(data).each(function() {
       alert(this+": "+this.id);
     });` and it outputs "result = success, data = [Object object],[Object object]" and then for each iteration in the loop it prints [Object object] : undefined. Why is the id property undefined? I see it clearly specified in the json string. what am I missing?